# How to expand CNN to recognize more objects?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I created a simple CNN to differentiate between 5 different categories of flowers. I want to expand the CNN to recognize more objects. For example, I want the CNN to recognize the image of a glass of beer, window, tree etc. 
Below is the code that I made to classify the flowers, it works pretty good. But how to expand it and make it recognise more and more objects. I don't want to use any pre-trained models. I want it to learn to classify more objects. Please help.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
classifier=Sequential()
#1st Convolution Layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(64,64,3),activation="relu"))
#Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))

# Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128, activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 64, activation = 'relu'))

classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 5, activation = 'softmax'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(classifier.summary())

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set= train_datagen.flow_from_directory('flowers/train_set',
                                                target_size=(64,64),
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                class_mode='categorical')


test_set= test_datagen.flow_from_directory('flowers/test_set',
                                                target_size=(64,64),
                                                batch_size=32,
                                                class_mode='categorical')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         samples_per_epoch = 3000,
                         nb_epoch = 25,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         nb_val_samples=1000)
```

Comment: Search about 'Fine tuning' or 'incremental learning'. the former is for manualy add new class, the latter is for automaticaly add new class, but this architecture is totaly different, so you will have to rewrite your code.
Also note that generally, in fine tuning, you start with a network pretrained on a huge dataset, and you use it to fine tuned a network with less classes and a smaller dataset. You seems to want the opposite.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I'll have to re-write the code though. It isnt possible to create a model which can learn to classify new objects(by adding more classes while retaining the previous ones) without using a pre-trained model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your own model and not fine tune a pretrained model like Vgg or inception (for examples), you should read this paper :

[iCaRL an incremnetal network (paper)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07725.pdf)

Of course you have to change your algorithm and your code. I find this github repo, apparently they implement it already : [Github repo for iCaRL in tensorflow](https://github.com/srebuffi/iCaRL/tree/master/iCaRL-Tensorflow)

But you have to use tensorflow. Look at it to learn how to use it with your model (if possible, I just find the paper and this repo today, so I haven't looked at it yet).

What you are asking is still in research domain, so there are not broad or common techniques yet.
As I said in my comment, search for the keyword "incremental learning", there are others papers on this subject. (look at the Related work session of the iCaRL paper, all the main techniques and papers for this subject are well summarized !)

Also, please note that add objects that is very different from your previous dataset (with your example of flowers + beer or window), should decrease your accuracy a lot.
You will have to train longer to have a better accuracy (but it may possible that your accuracy never increase as it was before)

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you are doing is called transfer learning  (fine-tuning), let me give you an example: Imganet is the world biggest image database for visual recognition it contains 1000 classes from al over reel world object like animals, cars..., the original neural network such as VGG16, Inception Net were trained to regonagnize each one of those object based on this data set. Imagine that you have a  dataset which is very small like 1000 image and you want to classify it to 3 classes, but your network fails because the image site is too small, you take VGG16 or inception Net you cut the last .

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1000, activation = 'softmax'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 3, activation = 'softmax'))
```

and you re-train juste the last layer , so decision making or classification is done over the lasy dense layer and it size define how many classe you want to classifiy each input to .

Comment: So i'll have to use a pre-trained model and cant teach my model to learn more and more classes by training it? Seems like i'll have to re-write the code after all so i edited the original post.

Comment: after getting the tarined model all what you need is to load the weights and remove last dense layer and replace it with your new one, it's extremly easy if you are familiar with deep learning frameworks but in case you aren't here are a good source where i learned this thing http://course.fast.ai/